# HardOps - Can't change default autosmooth angle

Tags: add-on

[image]

Select object > Q > Bevel then smooth shading and auto smooth is enabled automatically. Problem is that the default auto smooth angle is 60 degrees and I would like to set the default to 30. When I open the HOps Helper menu to set it to 30, it works only for that object. If I were to add in another object and apply bevel the same way, the auto smooth angle would still be 60 degrees. Is this a design flaw or is it just meant to be that way?

Comment: Hardops is a third-party addon, so best to ask on the official site.

Comment: @JohnEason I've tried searching, doesn't seem that there is a forum for it though. Could be wrong

Comment: You could try mailing the author directly via [this link](https://hardops-manual.readthedocs.io/en/master/#email) on the [Docs start page](https://hardops-manual.readthedocs.io/en/master/).